# Handle scope variables with handlebars

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

Using handlebars-1.1.2 and old emberjs 1.5.1.

I just need to put one variable in label's "for":

```
<label for='{{queue.id}}'>
```

Instead

```
<label for="6">
```

i get

```
<label for="<script id=" metamorph-51-start'="" type="text/x-placeholder">6<script id="metamorph-51-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>'&gt;<script id="metamorph-52-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Очередь через личный кабинет<script id="metamorph-52-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></label>
```

If i simply use {{queue.id}} inside the template it works okay.

How can I pass that value inside html attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In this version of emberjs I should write

```
<label {{bind-attr for=queue.id}}>
```