# How to pass object to handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using handlebars-1.1.2 and old emberjs 1.5.1.
I've code:

```
{{#each queue in appController.queues_services_array}}
    <label for="{{GetObjectId queue}}">{{queue.title}}</label></div>
{{/each}}
```

and helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('GetObjectId', function(value) {
  return value.id;
});
```

The problem is that data given to helper is just **string** "queue", not an object. I wonder how can I pass **object** "queue" to helper.

Comment: Why not do `for="{{queue.id}}"`?

Comment: try "this" instead of "queue", the problem to my mind is that you are in a #each loop and that inside your loop queue means actually queue.queue

Comment: That's a good one. Also curious, why is the Ember version so old? Have you tried refactoring to a more recent version?

Comment: %Jon Koops: it doesn't work, described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728305/handle-scope-variables-with-handlebars)

Comment: Have you tried using `bind-attr`? You should be able to do: `<label {{bind-attr for=queue.id}}>...`.

Comment: Or if you never expect the value to change you could use unbound: `<label for="{{unbound queue.id}}">...`

Comment: %Christophe Thiry `this` resolves empty string

Comment: I am a but rusty, has been a while to see such an old version of Ember. These things have become quite trivial in newer versions.

Comment: %Jon Koops, `{{bind-attr for=queue.id}}` worked okay) At last, thanks. Post your aswer, if you want, I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [bind-attr](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/) helper to bind your value to a specific attribute:

```
<label {{bind-attr for=queue.id}}>{{queue.title}}</label>
```

Or alternatively if you do not expect the value to change it is possible to use the unbound helper, which yields some improved performance:

```
<label for="{{unbound queue.id}}">{{queue.title}}</label>
```

The best thing you could do would be to update to a newer version of Ember so you could make use of the newer syntax which allows you to use regular Handlebars:

```
<label for="{{queue.id}}">{{queue.title}}</label>
```

Assuming you have the time and budget.